# How to call project to project?

Tags: android

I have Project A and I want to Call project B function to decrypt and encrypt the password.
In project B, it has var key and decrypts,encrypt function.
how can I call project b from project A without seeing any variable value? I meant as a Project A it can call Project B function and but I can't know the encrypt key in android java and swift iOS.

Comment: Do you mean different project o classes?, please read [ask] and add more details to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create project B as an android library, when you compile for first time, it will create .aar file. Then add that .aar file as a dependency to project A.

Use proguard, if possible to obfuscate your code:

look here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

NOTE: Everything is hackable, so don't sure about the code security.

Comment: Thanks,it work.Is there any solution for ios swift3